# What logo not showing on yahoo mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

My phpmailer works fine, but the logo wont show on yahoomail but it's showing on webmail. what could be possibly wrong?

I have done everthing I possibly could.

Thanks.

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'username';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'email@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'John Doe';
$mail->addAddress('email@eaxample.com', 'John Doe');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('email@eaxample.com.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('email@eaxample.com.com', 'John Doe');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('logo.png', 'logoimage');
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'THINKING ALOUD';
$mail->Body    = '
<img src="cid:logoimage">
<h2>Welcome</h2>
Hello. It me <b>Everyone!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Hello, its me Everyone';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: may be the mail settings in your yaoomail. if there is any options like 'show images for this mail' like. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks.
I've found out why the problem occurred. the problem is $mail->addAttachment('logo.png', 'logoimage'). I changed to $mail->embedImage('logo.png', 'logoimage', 'logo.png') voila! it worked.

so the addAttachment is recognized only as an attachment but webmail still reads it but yahoo wouldnt

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for another method. Instead:

> $mail->addAttachment('logo.png', 'logoimage');

Use following code to embedded image into mail:

> $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('logo.png', 'logoimage');

Reference: [PHPMailer method list](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=methods)